# Hide "Teams" under user profile if none

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, old-teams

Users are not obligated to be in a team, but the section is oriented on top of the other sections like accounts in the network profile and hot posts, despite not having much of an importance. As a lot of users aren't going to participate in teams by default, showing the empty section wastes a lot of space. It should be hidden in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen in the next build!